# How can I update my existing database table using domain class in grails 3.3.0?

Tags: grails, database-migration, grails-plugin, grails-3.3.0

I would like to add new column in my existed table using domain class but it is not happening. if I use create-drop in application.yml file then it works but at the same time I lost my data. I needed to keep the data as well as I needed to add new column by updating domain class property in grails 3.3.0 and SQL Server 2012

package com.alumni

```
class Student
{
    String studentId
    String studentName
    String age

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Database is not updating with column address

Comment: Take a look at https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/database-migration

Comment: @MikeW I have tried this also but I can't understand why this is also not working for me, if possible please help with a another way or any important suggestion to use this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your code snippet, but it sounds like you're trying to add

```
String address
```

Note that columns are made `NOT NULL` by default, so if data exists in the table, it's attempting to add a non-nullable column, with null data on every row, so the column will fail to create.  You need to allow this column to be nullable in the constraints block as well

```
static constraints = {
  address(nullable: true)
}
```

If you add that, the column should create successfully.

Comment: is there any other way to do this -please notify me if possible

Comment: Need more information about what you're doing, what is your actual code?  Show your domain object, you implied you're trying to add an "address" field, but didn't show that.  What error message are you getting when it tries to create the column?  What database are you using.  It's hard to give valuable feedback without more information.